# Rcpp function with List arguments returning a matrix

Tags: c++, r, performance, rcpp, rcpparmadillo

I have a section of code in [r](/questions/tagged/r) that is running quite slowly, and so I'm hoping to rewrite the function in [rcpp](/questions/tagged/rcpp), however, this is my first attempt using Rcpp, and I cannot get the code to compile or run.

In R, the section I am trying to rewrite is

```
  drawsamples<-lapply(1:numstudies,function(v){
      temp<-t(mapply(rmvn,n=1,mu=finalmu_b2_l[[v]],sigma=finalcov_b2_l[[v]]))
      rownames(temp)<-id[[v]]
      temp
    })
```

This code should return a nested [l](/questions/tagged/l)ist of matrices.  The list should be of length `numstudies` and each element of it should be a [matrix](/questions/tagged/matrix) of dimension `n[v]` rows by `ql` columns.  Each row of these matrices should be draws from a multivariate normal distribution, however the draws for each row will be controlled by a different mean vector `finalmu_b2_l` and a different covariance matrix `finalcov_b2_l`.  Both `finalmu_b2_l` and `finalcov_b2_l` are nested lists, top level of length `numstudies`, each element of which is a list of length `n[v]`.

So far, I have tried to write a piece of [rcpp](/questions/tagged/rcpp) code that will just draw one of the matrices needed, but want to extend this to return a list of matrices as soon as possible.  The code is below:

```
#include <RcppDist.h>
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppDist,RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat draw_b(const int n,
                 const int ql,
                 const Rcpp::List mu,
                 const Rcpp::List cov) {
  arma::mat draws = arma::zeros(n,ql);
  for (int iter = 1; iter <= n; iter++) {
     draws.row(iter) = rmvnorm(1, mu[iter], cov[iter]);
  }
  return draws;
}
```

Any time I try to compile the code (by sourcing the .cpp file the code is held in, using function `sourceCpp`), I get an error reading:

> invalid initialization of reference of type 'const::mat&'

, which I understand as an issue either with creating the `draws` matrix or with filling it?

Any advice, pointers or guidance on -

1. why this code is not compiling, what I should be doing in Rcpp instead, and/or
2. how to expand this to return a list of matrices rather than just a single matrix would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT

The original r code contains a mapply function nested within a lapply function.  I wanted to have an output that is a list length numstudies, each element of which is a matrix.  Each row of each matrix within this list is a relisation from a different multivariate normal distribution (so within each list element, for each row of the matrix, there is a unique mean vector and a unique covariance matrix controlling the multivariate normal I want to draw from).  I'd written as a mapply nested within a lapply to automatically give the output format I wanted, whilst allowing draws from different distributions for each matrix row.

EDIT2

After changing the iteration to run from 0 instead of 1, the following code compiles:

```
#include <RcppDist.h>
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppDist,RcppArmadillo)]]


//' @keywords internal
// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat draw_b(const int & n,
                 const int & ql,
                 const Rcpp::List & mu,
                 const Rcpp::List & cov) {
  arma::mat draws = arma::zeros(n,ql);
  for (int iter = 0; iter <= n; iter++ ) {
     draws.row(iter) = rmvnorm(1, mu_temp, cov_temp);
  }
  return draws;
}
```

EDIT3

The code currently compiles, but does not draw samples.  Instead I get the following error message:

```
error: Mat::init(): requested size is not compatible with column vector layout
Error in draw_b(n = n, ql = ql, mu = mu_example, cov = cov_example) : 
  Mat::init(): requested size is not compatible with column vector layout
```

I've prepared an example of what I would like this basic function to do (that just samples a matrix of realisations from different multivariate normal distributions.

Data:

```
list(n = 10, ql = 2, mu_example = list(c(0.342909965003207, -0.788070875792469
), c(-0.00499810116271365, 0.0114865660452949), c(-0.149753928200309, 
0.344162379034614), c(0.335176829763227, -0.770298692761465), 
    c(0.254206123984596, -0.584212951520601), c(0.379893097582703, 
    -0.873064992779416), c(0.137231089484867, -0.315382566602526
    ), c(0.405123380985852, -0.931048876501857), c(-0.00505917031396947, 
    0.0116269143128456), c(-0.0743318653279181, 0.170828451158346
    )), cov_example = list(structure(c(0.199912910315971, -0.459437048770092, 
-0.459437048770092, 4.49223135519527), .Dim = c(2L, 2L)), structure(c(0.199912910315971, 
-0.459437048770092, -0.459437048770092, 4.49223135519527), .Dim = c(2L, 
2L)), structure(c(0.199912910315971, -0.459437048770092, -0.459437048770092, 
4.49223135519527), .Dim = c(2L, 2L)), structure(c(0.199912910315971, 
-0.459437048770092, -0.459437048770092, 4.49223135519527), .Dim = c(2L, 
2L)), structure(c(0.199912910315971, -0.459437048770092, -0.459437048770092, 
4.49223135519527), .Dim = c(2L, 2L)), structure(c(0.199912910315971, 
-0.459437048770092, -0.459437048770092, 4.49223135519527), .Dim = c(2L, 
2L)), structure(c(0.199912910315971, -0.459437048770092, -0.459437048770092, 
4.49223135519527), .Dim = c(2L, 2L)), structure(c(0.199912910315971, 
-0.459437048770092, -0.459437048770092, 4.49223135519527), .Dim = c(2L, 
2L)), structure(c(0.199912910315971, -0.459437048770092, -0.459437048770092, 
4.49223135519527), .Dim = c(2L, 2L)), structure(c(0.199912910315971, 
-0.459437048770092, -0.459437048770092, 4.49223135519527), .Dim = c(2L, 
2L))))
```

R code

```
  drawsampletest<-draw_b(n=n,
                           ql=ql,
                           mu=mu_example,
                           cov=cov_example)
```

Rcpp code

```
#include <RcppDist.h>
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppDist,RcppArmadillo)]]


//' @keywords internal
// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat draw_b(const int & n,
                 const int & ql,
                 const Rcpp::List & mu,
                 const Rcpp::List & cov) {
  arma::mat draws = arma::zeros(n,ql);
  for (int iter = 0; iter <= n; iter++ ) {
    arma::rowvec mu_temp = mu[iter];
    arma::mat cov_temp = cov[iter];
    draws.row(iter) = rmvnorm(1, mu_temp, cov_temp);
  }
  return draws;
}
```

Of course once this is working- I still need to extend this to draw a list of matrices rather than a single matrix

Comment: Have you tried filling columns instead of rows?

Comment: Also, make sure to use indices starting at 0.

Comment: I'm not sure your R code is doing what you think it is (or else I'm misunderstanding the description of your problem). Why do you have a `mapply()` call *within* the `lapply()` call? I think this question could benefit from a full [mcve]. For tips on making one in the context of `R`, see [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/8386140). In particular, adding your data (i.e. `numstudies`, `finalmu_b2_l`, and `finalcov_b2_l`) by [edit]ing your question to include the output of the R command `dput()` and adding some expected output would probably help.

Comment: I say this as general advice, but also b/c it's possible this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem); what you're really worried about is speed of execution, not that it occurs in C++, right? It could be that tweaking your R code improves almost as good as rewriting in C++ would. So, even if we could fix w/ your C++ code & advise you how to extend it to return a list w/o seeing your data, your data (or a subset of it, or made up data with the same structure) can help produce a higher quality answer by helping us understand the problem.

Comment: Also, by the way, your code compiles just fine for me? After making the change prompted by @F.Privé 's astute observation re: indexing, it seemed to function as expected as well. You might want to add your operating system, and `R`, `Rcpp`, and `RcppDist` versions (such as via `sessionInfo()`)

Comment: to answer a few of the comments, I index from 1 rather than 0 as I understood this code filled in each matrix row in turn - I assumed starting `iter` at 1 would start by filling the first row - is this incorrect?  I have tried multiple codings in R which were all slow- I need to evaluate the R function during model fitting iterations, so in total this part would be evaluated >100,000 times.  Even though by itself it doesn't take too long, given the number of evaluations needed I thought implementing in C might help.  I've tried to clarify why I have a mapply nested within lapply in an edit

Comment: I think I understand why you have `mapply()` now; I missed at first that they were lists of lists, that was my mistake. Re: indexing:  In R, the 1 element is the first element, but in C++ the 0 element is the first element. This should be pretty easy to finish out, but what's more troubling is the fact that the existing code isn't compiling for you. It compiles fine on my machine, which is why I mention adding the results of `sessionInfo()`

Comment: After some editing of the code I have a version that compiles - but it still will only draw one matrix, not a list of matrices - I'm trying to work on that version now, and have added the code that compiles for me in an edit in main question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a basic setup that should do what you want:

```cpp
#include <RcppDist.h>
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppDist,RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::mat draw_b(const int ql,
                 const Rcpp::List& mu,
                 const Rcpp::List& cov) {
    int n = mu.size();
    arma::mat draws = arma::zeros(n, ql);
    for ( arma::uword iter = 0; iter < n; iter++ ) {
        draws.row(iter) = rmvnorm(1, mu[iter], cov[iter]);
    }
    return draws;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List get_list_of_draws(Rcpp::List mu, Rcpp::List Sigma, int ql) {
    int numstudies = mu.size();
    Rcpp::List res(numstudies);
    for ( int iter = 0; iter < numstudies; ++iter ) {
        Rcpp::List mu_temp = mu[iter];
        Rcpp::List cov_temp = Sigma[iter];
        res[iter] = draw_b(ql, mu_temp, cov_temp);
    }
    return res;
}
```

It seems to work as expected:

```r
res <- get_list_of_draws(mu_example, cov_example, ql)
str(res)
# List of 1
#  $ : num [1:10, 1:2] -0.0156 -0.4717 -0.8134 0.5489 0.1215 ...
```

(Note though that when I set up `mu_example` and `cov_example` I wrapped them in `list()`s as you stated they should be lists of lists.)